# Spring Data Jpa Save and SaveAndFlush

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using (Spring Data) *JpaRepository* to perform CURD operation. Here I saw two methods *save* and *saveAndFlush*. in both methods I got the same result, it successfully save data in the database. So what is the difference? I'm not using any sort of transactions mechanism, to issues commit command with the *save* method.

```
@Transactional
public BaseDto add(BulkPermitCategoryDto requestDto) {
    BaseDto baseDto = new BaseDto();
    try {
        BulkPermitCategory category = ObjectConverter
                .bulkPermitCategoryDtoToBulkPermitCategory(requestDto);
        bulkPermitCategoryRepository.saveAndFlush(category);
        baseDto.setStatusCode(0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("exception occered ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return baseDto;
}
```

and

```
@Transactional
public BaseDto add(BulkPermitCategoryDto requestDto) {
    BaseDto baseDto = new BaseDto();
    try {
        BulkPermitCategory category = ObjectConverter
                .bulkPermitCategoryDtoToBulkPermitCategory(requestDto);
        bulkPermitCategoryRepository.save(category);
        baseDto.setStatusCode(0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("exception occered ", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return baseDto;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**save()**

`save()` is calling `EntityManager.persist()` or `EntityManager.merge()` this will not execute the SQL statements immediately. They will be executed on transaction commit.

**saveAndFlush()**

`saveAndFlush()` additionally calls `EntityManager.flush()` that will execute all retained SQL statements.

So if there are any constraint violations you will get the exceptions when calling `saveAndFlush()` but not when calling `save()`

Comment: But save() is @Transactional. So, it also saves sata immediately. At least. in my case. What's going on?

Comment: There are some cases where Hibernate must execute the SQL statements even when calling persist(). For example if you have GenerationType.IDENTITY and a MySQL DB with auto_increment.

Comment: Mu DB is Postgres. I guess the reason is FlushMode that is default in my project:



 /**
  * The {@link Session} is sometimes flushed before query execution
  * in order to ensure that queries never return stale state. This
  * is the default flush mode.
  */
 AUTO(10 ),

Comment: Yes if you have pending changes and are executing select statements the EntityManger flushes the changes to have a READ_COMMITED behavoir

Comment: I don't select after save(). And it flushes immediately.

Comment: In that case please create a new question with some code examples. We shouldn't discuss this here

Comment: No magic! I figured it out. If someone is intersted. How I checked that my entity is savet to DB? I used a wrong way. I executed a query in debug window. So, there was a select query! Not in my code, but I executed it during debug.